# Append more info to RSpec's default failure message?

Tags: rspec

I'm testing a lot of bad strings on a validation like this:

```
['0', '3:a', 'xx:11', '-1', '-3:00', 'h', 'h2', 'h2h', 'm', 'm10', 'm10m', '2hm', 'h2m', 'hm2', '2m10h', '2m10m', '2h10h'].each do |input|
  FactoryGirl.build(:time_record, duration_string: input).should have(1).error_on('duration_string'), "Tested value was '#{input}'"
end
```

Sadly, when one of them fails, the message `expected 1 error on :duration_string, got 0` doesn't tell me, which one failed. I know that I can pass a second argument that is displayed instead of the default message like this:

```
x.should have(1).error_on('duration_string'), "Tested value was '#{input}'"
```

But this hides the original message. Is there a way to only append my own message to the original instead of replacing it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
['0', '3:a', 'xx:11', '-1', '-3:00', 'h', 'h2', 'h2h', 'm', 'm10', 'm10m', '2hm', 'h2m', 'hm2', '2m10h', '2m10m', '2h10h'].each do |input|
  it "does not accept #{input}" do
    FactoryGirl.build(:time_record, duration_string: input).should have(1).error_on('duration_string'), "Tested value was '#{input}'"
  end
end
```

This way you also get cheaply a higher specs count for your statistics. ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can catch and reraise exception with another message:

```
['0', '3:a', 'xx:11', '-1', '-3:00', 'h', 'h2', 'h2h', 'm', 'm10', 'm10m', '2hm', 'h2m', 'hm2', '2m10h', '2m10m', '2h10h'].each do |input|
  begin
    FactoryGirl.build(:time_record, duration_string: input).should  have(1).error_on('duration_string'), "Tested value was '#{input}'"
  rescue RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError => e
    e.message << "failed at #{input}"
    raise e
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I meanwhile solved it another way, see my new answer.