# Is it possible to append some text to RSpec failure message whenever expectation fails inside block?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Say, I have a have a block like

```
(1..10).each do |number|
  c.should == d
  array1.empty? should_not be_false
  array2.empty? should be_true
  result.should eq(3)
end
```

I'd like to append text like `"failed at #{number}"` to failure message whenever expectation fails inside this block.

I can do it like:

```
(1..10).each do |number|
  message = "failed at #{number}"
  c.should == d, message
  array1.empty? should_not be_false, message
  array2.empty? should be_true, message
  result.should eq(3), message
end
```

But:

1. It's not DRY (I should write `, message` at every row)
2. This message overrides default RSpec message. I'd want to somehow append to it to default RSpec message

Comment: Here is similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/14379941/841064

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch and reraise exception with another message:

```
(1..10).each do |number|
  begin
    c.should == d
    array1.empty? should_not be_false
    array2.empty? should be_true
    result.should eq(3)
  rescue RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError => e
    e.message << "failed at #{number}"
    raise e
  end
end
```